# Delete a node based on matching data

Tags: c, linked-list

Directions: Implement the following function to search by last name and then delete the first matching student from the linked-list. If a matching student is found, the function returns a pointer to the head of the new linked-list; if a matching student is not found, the list is unchanged and the head of the linked-list is returned.

When compiling and running this code, it only deletes the head node each time. Even if the name is in the middle of the list or not in the list at all, the head node is always deleted. Not really sure whats going wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
STUDENT *DeleteByLastName(STUDENT *students, char *name)
{
struct STUDENT* current = students;
struct STUDENT* previous = NULL;

while (current != NULL) {
  if (current->Lastname == name) {
     if (previous == NULL) {
        current = current->Next;
        free(students);
        students = current;
     }
     else {
        previous->Next = current->Next;
        free(current);
        current = previous->Next;
     }
  } 
  else {
     previous = current;
     current = current->Next;
  }
  return current;
}    
return NULL;

}
```

Comment: `current->Lastname == name` - this is not the way to compare strings. Use `strcmp` family. Which makes me suspect you have similar problems in the functions you don't show...

Comment: Tip; `char *name` should be `const char *name` since you don't modify that to which `name` points.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips! Here's the code that I got to work for anyone interested.

```
STUDENT *DeleteByLastName(STUDENT *students, char *name)
{
struct STUDENT* current;
struct STUDENT* head = students;

current = students;
int count = 0;
struct STUDENT* previous = NULL;

while (current != NULL) {
    //check for matching head and delete
    if (strcmp(current->Lastname,name) == 0 && count == 0) {
        students = current->Next;
        return students;
    }
    //If name matches but is not at the beggining of the list
    if(strcmp(current->Lastname,name) == 0) {
        previous->Next = previous->Next->Next;
        current = current->Next;
        return students;
    }
    else {
        previous = current;
        current = current->Next;
        ++count;
    }
}
return head;
}
```